# can some one find why this sql query is is throwings error

Tags: sql, postgresql

```
SELECT facid, sum(slots*cost) AS revenue FROM
(SELECT *, CASE WHEN memid=0 THEN guestcost ELSE membercost END AS cost)
FROM 
(SELECT * FROM nina_driver.country_club_facilities a
INNER join nina_driver.country_club_bookings b
ON a.facid=b.facid)SAMPLE) T1
GROUP BY facid
HAVING sum(slots*cost)<1000
```

getting error

> ERROR: relation "cd.facilities" does not exist   Position: 169
>   -- Returns first 100 rows from nina_driver.country_club_bookings
>                                         ^ SELECT * FROM nina_driver.country_club_bookings LIMIT 100;

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: The close parenthesis at the end of the second line looks like a mistake.

Comment: Your parentheses are not balanced the `from (SELECT *, ... AS cost) FROM (...)` is missing a join or something else. Also the error message doesn't match your query as there is no LIMIT 100 in your query

Comment: i am using mode analytics i think they have there own DBMS

Comment: Better code formatting would have made this easy to spot.

Comment: can u type correct syntex

Comment: If you try to format your query this gets obvious: http://dpaste.com/1BHA5E6

Comment: @sahil . . . Nothing is called `cd.facilities` in your code so it seems doubtful that this code could generate that error.

Comment: This is too far removed from proper SQL syntax to be understood. It is *all* wrong. So I don't see how the question can be answered.